# Bug with multiple OpenID accounts

Tags: bug, openid, google-openid

I use my Google account to authenticate to Stack Exchange. I created a Stack Exchange OpenID account using the same GMail email address as the account handle. I then added that new Stack Exchange OpenID as an authentication method to my Stack Exchange network profile.

Upon doing so, the Google account with the same email address was no longer listed, and could no longer be used to login. I was subsequently able to add the Google auth account back, but it probably shouldn't have been deleted in the first place.

Is this a bug?

Comment: You know what, I think I remember this happening to me when I was testing the new login system on meta but didn't think much of it at the time.  My SE Open ID has the same email address as my SE Open Id account as well and I had to re-add my gmail login too.

Comment: I can see 4 different logins on your account - 2 of them with the same email address (1 a Stack Exchange openId, the other via Google). Can you confirm that you are not seeing the same under the "my logins" section?

Comment: @Oded: I confirm that I *AM* seeing the same thing. 4 logins, two of which have the same email. It is the two logins with the same email which caused the buggy behavior (I presume) which I described in my question. Although the first account was deleted, I later added it back (which I mentioned in my post), which is why you and I both currently see all 4, including both dups.